# Continuity of piece-wise function - check my proof

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, continuity

Check at which points $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$,

$$f{x \choose y}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} x, & y=0 \\
         y, & x=0\\ 0, & else \end{array}\right.
$$

is continuous.

My approach:

1.) All points ${x \choose y}$ with $x\neq 0$ and $y = 0$:

Let $lim_{n\to\infty} {x_n \choose y_n} = {x \choose y}$, with $y_n \neq 0 ~\forall n$, be a convergent sequence. If we plug in the sequence into $f$ we get $lim_{n\to\infty}f{x_n \choose y_n}=0 \neq x = f{x \choose y}$. Hence, $f$ is not continuous at those points.

2.) At point ${0 \choose 0}$:

Let $lim_{n\to\infty} {x_n \choose y_n} = {0 \choose 0}$, with $x_n = 0$ and $ y_n \neq 0 ~\forall n$, be a convergent sequence. If we plug in the sequence into $f$ we get $lim_{n\to\infty}f{x_n \choose y_n}=lim_{n\to\infty}y_n =0= f{x \choose y}$.  The same holds if I plug in a convergent sequence $lim_{n\to\infty} {x_n \choose y_n} = {0 \choose 0}$, with $x_n \neq 0$ and $ y_n = 0 ~\forall n$ or $x_n \neq 0$ and $ y_n \neq 0 ~\forall n$.  Hence, $f$ is continuous at ${0 \choose 0}$.

3.) All points ${x \choose y}$ with $x\neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$:

Let $lim_{n\to\infty} {x_n \choose y_n} = {x \choose y}$, with $x_n \neq 0$ and $ y_n \neq 0 ~\forall n$, be a convergent sequence. If we plug in the sequence into $f$ we get $lim_{n\to\infty}f{x_n \choose y_n}=0 = f{x \choose y}$. Hence, $f$ is continuous at those points.

4.) All points ${x \choose y}$ with $x= 0$ and $y \neq 0$:

Let $lim_{n\to\infty} {x_n \choose y_n} = {x \choose y}$, with $x_n \neq 0$ and $ y_n \neq 0 ~\forall n$, be a convergent sequence. If we plug in the sequence into $f$ we get $lim_{n\to\infty}f{x_n \choose y_n}=0 \neq y= f{x \choose y}$. Hence, $f$ is not continuous at those points.

Is this correct? Or would you do it differently?

Comment: The answers for 3 and 4 should be identical by symmetry. The function doesn't change if you switch $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta, you mean 1 and 4 are symmetric, right?

Answer (score 0):

You make a mistake in $2)$. 
It should be $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{f(x_n,y_n)} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{x_n} = 0$ as $y_n \to 0$.

If you get stuck with such exercises: try to visualize the functions in order to get a better understanding on whether they are or are not continuous.

Comment: I forgot taking the limit. I have edited my question. So, this means that $f$ is continuous at ${0 \choose 0}$, right?